# Center This CarouFredSel Carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, caroufredsel

I am using the jQuery CarouFredSel plugin for my carousel and I am trying to center it. I have tried to apply `margin:0 auto;` to the head carousel tag `#c-carousel` but nothing happened. I think it might be because I did not specify a width, however when I do specify a width part of the carousel becomes cut off.

What I'm trying to do with my carousel is similar to the carousel located on [Blizzard's homepage](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/) where the carousel will rotate through a bunch of images with links, but will not cause the horizontal scroll bars to appear if the browser is narrower then the carousel content.

Code:

```
<div id="c-carousel">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="caroufredsel_wrapper">
            <div id="carousel">
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1200x650/ff0000/999999">
                    <div class="content"><a href="">link</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1200x650/00ff00/999999">
                    <div class="content"><a href="">link</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1200x650/0000ff/999999">
                    <div class="content"><a href="">link</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1200x650/f0f0ff/999999">
                    <div class="content"><a href="">link</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pager">
        <a href="http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/18/#" class="selected"><span>1</span></a>
        <a href="http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/18/#" class=""><span>2</span></a>
        <a href="http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/18/#" class=""><span>3</span></a>
        <a href="http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/18/#" class=""><span>4</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    content
</div>

$(function() {
    $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
        scroll: {
            fx: 'crossfade',
            duration: 1000
        },
        pagination: {
            container: '#pager',
            duration: 500
        }
    });
});


#c-carousel {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 600px;
    min-width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.caroufredsel_wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
#carousel .slide {
    width:1200px;
    height:650px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10000px;
}
#carousel .slide .content {
    font-size: 55pt;
    position: relative;
    top: -300px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 5;
}
#carousel .slide img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#pager {
    position: relative;
    top: -250px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
}
#pager a {
    background-color: #356;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #cef;
}
#pager a.selected {
    background-color: #134;
}
#pager a span {
    display: none;
}

#content {
    background: yellow;
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 20px;
    top: -200px;
    font-size: 80pt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your code adjusted here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Esrm/

add to #c-carousel the property:

```
width:960px;
```

and remove min-width. This will make margin work.

add this CSS:

```
body {overflow-x:hidden}
```

this will make the page ignore if the content on x axis is bigger then the view port and will not display a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: When I added `#c-carousel{width:960px;}` it sliced off part of my carousel image. When I added `body{overflow-x:hidden;}` the scroll bars no longer appear when the browser width is less then 960px (width of my content).